# Как не унаследовать padding?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Всем привет. В `#container` расположен блок `.player`:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="player">
</div>
</div>
```

У `#container` в CSS прописан `padding: 1%;`.

```
#container {
padding: 1%;
}
```

Как сделать так, что бы `.player` не унасделовал `padding` от `#container?` (пробовал `!important`)

Comment: @misc, padding не наследуется

Comment: @Etki, вкурсе - но у меня получается что как то наследуется.

Comment: @misc, ставлю традиционные пять баксов, что даже у вас не происходит никакой магии и ничего не наследуется. Откройте инспектор да посмотрите.

Comment: @Etki создал на jsbin страницу: http://jsbin.com/bihawepuzu

Comment: @misc, тогда дело в чем-то еще, данный код проблем не вызывает и наследование не происходит: http://jsfiddle.net/cx7939j1/ Попробуйте локализовать проблему или сделать работоспособный пример.

----------

UPD: @misc, на вашей странице в jsbin тоже нет наследования. Есть padding у container, который сдвигает картинку вправо, но у самого .player свойство padding не установлено и не наследуется. Как и в моем примере на jsfiddle.